# Own program writes 300 small files. In that time explorer.exe draws nearly 100% CPU time

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, ntfs

A C# application I developed writes 300 small (1k) files to a local filesystem (NTFS).
During that time explorer.exe uses up to 100% CPU time.

Things I already sorted out:

- Assured that no explorer windows are open displaying the target folder
- Excluded indexing for the target folder
- Expluded indexing for that complete drive
- Stopped and disabled the services "Windows Search" (SearchIndexer.exe)

All of this with no effect.

When I use Systinternals ProcessExplorer I see one busy thread of explorer.exe that states most of the time:

```
ntdll.dll!RtIFreeUnicodeString+0x1370
```

And its stack look like this:

```
0  msvcrt.dll!memcpy+0x8a
1  SHELL32.dll!Ordinal755+0x75c
2  SHELL32.dll!PathYetAnotherMakeUniqueName+0x35316
3  SHELL32.dll!ExtractIconExW+0xed8
4  SHELL32.dll!ExtractIconW+0x98e5
5  SHELL32.dll!SHChangeNotification_Lock+0x4179
6  SHELL32.dll!DAD_SetDragImage+0x1018
7  SHELL32.dll!DAD_SetDragImage+0x11ef
8  SHCORE.dll!GetProcessReference+0x3f
9  ntdll.dll!RtlDestroyHeap+0x317
10 ntdll.dll!RtlFreeUnicodeString+0x17d5
11 KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
12 ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
```

What is explorer.exe doing here? Is there a direct dependency between the filesystem and the explorer?
And how can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: There's no UI thread. Writing happens in an own thread. However, the problem also manifests in the corresponding UnitTest, that just generated all these files

Comment: You could use a tool like [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find out what the busiest threads of Explorer.exe are actually doing.

Comment: @Axel Kemper: I add some output of ProcessExplorer. At position 5 it says "SHChangeNotification_Lock". Is explorer notifying some processes about each new file?

Comment: Are you initiallizing and freeing a "string" or other object inside a loop? Are you able to allow a doevents call every nth iteration?

Comment: antivius is off?  no other programs with filesystem hooks that might be reading the file?

Comment: ProcessExplorer only shows a snapshot. Use WPR/WPA (http://superuser.com/a/1066939/174557) instead and expand the Explorer stack to see which functions are called very often by Explorer

Comment: @Yorik: It's not about my process. It's explorer.exe that does "weird" things.

Comment: @magicandre1981: I already had multiple looks at the stack. And most of the time it looked like the one posted. However, i will have a look into WPR/WPA.

Comment: again, using procexp only shows a snapshot, you don't see what happened before. WPA sumps up all calls and here you see the hotspots easily

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to all your comments. I was able to track down the consumed CPU time to Windows Defender which was notified about new files by explorer.exe

Excluding some relevant directories there helped.

The thing that puzzled me was the fact that the CPU was consumed by explorer, not by defender...
Otherwise it would have been more obvious

Comment: Apps can ask explorer to monitor a  directoryfor changes.  That's probably why Explorer got involved.